# TypeError: game.HexRenderer is not a constructor on Linux Mint

Tags: javascript, linux, melonjs

I have:

HexRenderer.js:

```
/**
 * HexRenderer
 */
game.HexRenderer = game.HexRenderer || {};

game.HexRenderer = me.Renderable.extend({

    init : function() {
        //init logic
    },

    draw : function(context) {
       //draw logic
    },

    update : function() {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Play.js:

```
game.PlayScreen = me.ScreenObject.extend({
    /** 
     *  action to perform on state change
     */
    onResetEvent: function() {

        // load a level
        me.levelDirector.loadLevel("hextile");

        // reset the score
        game.data.score = 0;

        // add our HexRenderer to the game world
        //console.log(typeof(game.HexRenderer)); - undefined
        this.hexagonGrid = new game.HexRenderer(); // Error appears here
        me.game.world.addChild(this.hexagonGrid);
    },


    /** 
     *  action to perform when leaving this screen (state change)
     */
    onDestroyEvent: function() {
        // remove the HexRenderer from the game world
        me.game.world.removeChild(this.hexagonGrid);
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
    <!-- melonJS Library -->
    <!-- build:js js/app.min.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/melonJS-2.0.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin(s) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/plugins/debug/debugPanel.js"></script>

    <!-- Game Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/melon/entities/HexRenderer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/melon/Game.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/melon/Resources.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/melon/entities/Entities.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/melon/screens/Title.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/melon/screens/Play.js"></script>
```

Code is based on melonjs [tutorial](http://melonjs.github.io/tutorial-platformer/).

On launching I see:

> TypeError: game.HexRenderer is not a constructor

The thing is that **everything works just fine in Windows**, but **doesn't work on Linux Mint**(Tried in last chrome and firefox version).

Is it some trick ? What's the difference, how it related to OS?

Comment: I would try getting rid of the line `game.HexRenderer = game.HexRenderer || {};` just in case, as it shouldn't do anything anyways. It's possible the javascript optimization is stopping at that for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, this was first thing that I tried to do, but unfortunately without any luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah,  it was very stupid issue.

That was quite far from melonjs.

On index.html I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/melon/entities/HexRenderer.js"></script>
```

But file name was hexRenderer.js, I changed it to HexRenderer.js and everything started to work.
Weird thing that it worked on windows...(See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382114/case-sensitivity-on-linux-and-windows-for-javascript-imports-in-html))