# Case sensitivity on linux and windows for javascript imports in html

Tags: javascript, html, linux

I have follow:

test.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
  alert(Test);
</script>
```

test.js:

```
var Test="test";
```

The question is **why it works on Windows and doesn't work on Linux** ( in other words why linux is case sensative for imports , but window isn't)?

How can I switch off case sensitivity for javascript imports on Linux?

Comment: This is to do with the type of filesystem running on the hard drives or ssds

Comment: Yeah, I developed my JS game via file:// so I didn't see "404" errors for imports on console, because of lot of js files it was quite difficult to find error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, `test.js` and `Test.js` are two separate files because of case-sensitivity on most file-systems.

You can change this at file-system level by using the [ciopfs - Case Insensitive On Purpose File System](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/) that allows you to mount a directory as a case-insensitive file-system.

Or, you can change this at webserver level. F.e. if the Linux server is running Apache, you can add a `.htaccess` file that uses [mod_spelling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html) with these options:

```
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
```

But personnaly, I think you should fix the casing instead.

Comment: Added a way to configure the webserver instead, might be easier than working with ciopfs